# POST массив приходит пустым

Tags: post, ajax, php, apache2.2, codeigniter

Добрый день! Имею сайт на CodeIgniter и его тестовую ветку. По сути все файлы там одинаковые, просто перед обновлением все проверяется на тесте, а потом делается полное копирование в продакшн.

Суть в том, что на сайте есть форма, отправляемая через ajax. На тестовой ветке она работает отлично, но на продакшене приходит пустой post-массив.
Как отследить, в чем проблема?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Нужно глянуть на код. 

Возможно настройки php на локальном сервере и хостинге разные и что то там не чисто 

Comment: все на одном сервере, в соседних папках

Comment: сложно сказать без кода

Answer (score 1):

Возможно на продакшене другой `.htaccess`, который перенаправляет все запросы с `http://site.com/path` на `http://site.com/path/` (слэш в конце) или наоборот. Посмотрите, какой Вы формируете адрес для отправки, и посмотрите, на какой адрес реально идет отправка. Нет ли там 301 редиректа? Если есть - просто добавьте/уберите слэш (зависит от настроек `.htaccess`)

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите что отсылает скрипт на сервер в консоли браузера, может быть он как раз и отсылает пустые данные.

Comment: суть в том и есть, что он отсылает POST массив и файл, а в ответ получает страницу. я сделал var_dump($_POST) на этой странице, а он пустой..

Comment: а зачем вы в CI используете $_POST ?

Comment: какая разница? он всегда работал так, год уже с ним работаю. Просто по привычке. Не вижу смысла писать $this->input->post() вместо $_POST['']

Comment: ну раз не видите...

Comment: Разница ощутима: $this->input->post() освобождает вас от конструкции if(!isset($_POST['data']) && empty($_POST['data'])), к тому же, второй параметр этой функции (True) включает XSS фильтр. Возможно, что функция выполняет элементарную валидацию, но нужно посмотреть...
А так, покажите код AJAX + PHP